# How to edit and change the title of oracle apex error messages?

Tags: oracle-apex

[image]

I need to edit the error title to Portuguese, the entire application is in Portuguese except these titles. Can anyone help me please?

My configuration: [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to control your exceptions using text messages and call that message using APEX_LANG.

Texts messages can be implemented in JavaScript as well.

```
  --PLSQL example
    BEGIN
      HTP.P(APEX_LANG.MESSAGE('GREETING_MSG', V('APP_USER')));
    END; 

  --SQL example
    select apex_lang.message(
      p_name => 'YOUR_TEXT_MESSAGE',
      p_application_id => :APP_ID
    )
    from dual;

   --JAVASCRIPT example
    var promise = apex.lang.loadMessages( ["MY_MESSAGE1", "MY_MESSAGE2"] );
    promise.done(function() {
        var text = apex.lang.getMessage("MY_MESSAGE1");
        // use text somehow
    }.fail(function() {
        apex.debug.error( "Could not get messages." );
    };
```

[image]

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/aeapi/MESSAGE-Function.html#GUID-0D2B9901-CEBB-4B99-A6EA-7D7B3CCA8F1A

Do not forget to change the default language of your app.

Comment: This is an internal string - the title of the error region. How can that be controlled with a custom message ?

Comment: In your code, you can RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'An error occurred. Please contact support.'); and use your own messages

Comment: Take a look of this link https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/aeapi/Example-of-an-Error-Handling-Function.html#GUID-2CD75881-1A59-4787-B04B-9AAEC14E1A82

Comment: You need to provide more details. When is this behavior happening? I mean, in which component? What kind of region?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test. Created a new application, set primary language to French. Created a page with a button and a validation. The error title came up in French:
[image]

So... something must be different in your app. Please provide as much info as possible to be able to exactly reproduce your question.

Comment: I already put my settings, can you help?

Comment: Pls provide as much info as possible. What version of apex, how are you getting this error, is it a validation ? Please describe exactly how to reproduce this error you're showing in the screenshot. If you create a new application like I showed, do you see this behaviour as well ?

Comment: My version of apex is Oracle APEX 22.1.0. This is a error of a constraint, but all errors comes in english.

Comment: Please describe exactly how to reproduce this error you're showing in the screenshot. If you create a new application like I showed, do you see this behaviour as well ?